# Is there a way to print out a list of all possible template files for a page?

Tags: 6, theming

Including template files used for views, rows, blocks, etc. on that page?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest review Theme Developer module http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer, it will help to find possible templates that can help to modify (theming) specific parts of your site.

in this resource http://drupal.org/node/209561 you will find how to use the module.

Comment: Yeah I know about devel_themer but it's slow and clunky and I'd prefer an alternative method.

Comment: @Joren, I suggest give a second chance to Theme Developer module, when the module is ready, only with two clicks it will show a list of possible options of templates. Due that is for test/development enviroments, is not for productions enviroments (in my case, I have disabled the module in test enviroments, because seems to have conflicts with some views, but when it has been necessary, has been very useful).